# Trying to create dynamic dropdown search fields

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert two dropdown boxes in my website where the selected option in the first dropdown influences the options in the second dropdown box. I can't understand why it won't work as when I click 'Car' in option 1 it has no effect on the options in the second dropdown box rather than fetching the relevant data.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function populate(s1, s2) {
    var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = " ";
    if (s1.value = "Car") {
      var optionArray = ["|", "honda|Honda", "bmw|Bmw", "fiat|Fiat"];
    }
    for (var option in optionArray) {
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      S2.options.add(newOption);
    }
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<form action="https://www.carlink.co.uk/products.php">
  <select name="slct 1" id="slct 1" onchange="populate('slct 1','slct 2')">
    <option disabled selected="Vehicle Type">Vehicle Type</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Van">Shotgun</option>
    <option value="Bike">Air rifle</option>
    <option value="Train">Air pistol</option>
  </select>


  <select name="slct 2" id="slct 2">
    <option disabled selected="make">Make</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code in JS Fiddle and the console logs an error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: S2 is not defined`

Your `S2.options...` should be `s2.options...`

Easy fix!

Comment: They also have `s1.value = "Car"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You had a couple of errors in your code. You should also try using a 3d array instead of spliting by `|` later on.

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  
  if (s1.value == "Car") {
    var optionArray = [["", ""], ["honda", "Honda"], ["bmw","Bmw"], ["fiat", "Fiat"]];
  }
  
  s2.innerHTML = "";
  
  for (let option in optionArray) {
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = optionArray[option][0];
    newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[option][1];
    s2.options.add(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.carlink.co.uk/products.php">
  <select name="slct 1" id="slct 1" onchange="populate('slct 1','slct 2')">
    <option disabled selected="Vehicle Type">Vehicle Type</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Van">Shotgun</option>
    <option value="Bike">Air rifle</option>
    <option value="Train">Air pistol</option>
  </select>


  <select name="slct 2" id="slct 2">
    <option disabled selected="make">Make</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 main issues with your code

- 1. Instead of using lower case `s2` you are accessing `S2.options`
- 2. You are using `s1.value = "Car"` which is simply invalid, it does not compare `s1.value` with `"Car"` you  should be using  the `==` or `===` operator(s)

Here is a working version

```js
function populate(s1, s2) {
  var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
  var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
  s2.innerHTML = " ";
  if (s1.value == "Car") { // You were using = instead of ==
    var optionArray = ["|", "honda|Honda", "bmw|Bmw", "fiat|Fiat"];
  }
  for (var option in optionArray) {
    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = pair[0];
    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
    s2.options.add(newOption); // Here you are using S2
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.carlink.co.uk/products.php">
  <select name="slct 1" id="slct 1" onchange="populate('slct 1','slct 2')">
    <option disabled selected="Vehicle Type">Vehicle Type</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Van">Shotgun</option>
    <option value="Bike">Air rifle</option>
    <option value="Train">Air pistol</option>
  </select>


  <select name="slct 2" id="slct 2">
    <option disabled selected="make">Make</option>
  </select>
```